# Why declare twice the type of a list in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

So, i'm just wondering why do we need to declare the type of a list two times on c#, as the example below:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

i worked with Lists (which are ArrayLists) on Java, but there we don't have to do this necessarily.

Comment: var products = new List<Product>();

Comment: It is *declaring* the type just once - the RHS is creating an instance

Comment: Simply Java != C#.

Comment: C++ and C used to have the same sort of limitation.

Comment: On the left side, you declare `products` to hold something from Type `List<Product>`. On the right side, you assign a `new List<Product>()` to the variable `products`. You do not declare the type two times

Comment: It is a limitation of the C# type inference feature.  Decently explained in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/).

Comment: @Hans Passant Good point - it was not clear from the question that it is a field, not a variable.

Comment: As commented above, this is not necessary in a function. However, for class members you still need to do it but usually that code would be written in the constructor body.

Comment: How do you do it in Java without declaring the type?

Comment: Declaration type of variables differs from creating the instance and attach them. Think about! One of the benefits is you can declare a variable as Super(Father) class and then create that as a child class in polymorphism

Comment: Can you give an example from the Java world? If memory serves me well, only the recently released Java 10 introduced the "var" keyword, and it has most of the limitations found in the decade old C# variant, including mandatory type declaration for fields.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. It is perfectly fine to just write

```
var products = new List<Product>();
```

as long as the variable is declared within the scope of a method.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

**Edit**:

If the question refers specifically to Java's [diamond operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_type_inference.htm) that allows you to write

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

then there are some excellent answers here:
[Diamond Syntax in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731423/diamond-syntax-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is also recomended if right part visibly define its type.

Comment: @eocron Yes, exactly.  I always try to remember to use var unless the type cannot visibly be inferred from the right part. But one place I keep forgetting to use it out of old habit is within for-loops, e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {...}`

Comment: Speaking about fields this answer is misleading to say the least.

Comment: @Antonín Lejsek I just added clarification to avoid any misunderstandings (although it is not clear to me that the question is about fields + the article I linked to actually states right at the top that the variable must be declared at method scope).

Comment: "why do we need to declare the type of a list two times" - this implies that we are talking about situations where we do have to. In other words, this sentence rules out cases where we do not have to declare the type twice (like methods variables).

Answer (score -4):

You are not delcaring the same thing twice.

`List<Product> products;` declares the variable of that type.

whereas

`products = new List<Product>();`

creates a instance and assigns it to the variable.

`List<Product> products = new List<Product>();` is simply a way to do **both** operations in one line.

Also note this regarding cases where the variable type and newly created isntance do not match: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321186/3346583 Apparently that is somewhat more common in Java, as I actually found it when looking for java examples.

Comment: Neither `List<object> products = new List<Product>();` nor `List<Product> products = new List<object>();` are valid, or am i missing something? Nice reference to the comic by the way (reminds me of that legendary "WTFJS" video about Javascript ;-) )

Comment: @elgonzo: I am not 100% sure it is right, but you are propably missing covaraince and contravariance: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/ Took me some time to learn of it myself. And I still have not fully wrapped my head around it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something there. Your code is trying to tell me i can stuff any non-product object into a product list (List<Product>) because it is a list of objects... ahem... (List<T> is not IEnumerable<T>!!!)

Comment: @elgonzo: Co- and Contravariance apply to **every** generic type. But you are right that my second example would not work. I need to fix that.

Comment: What??? (o.O)? No, they don't apply to every generic type. Only to those types whose generic type parameter(s) have been marked as such (using `in` or `out`).

Comment: Again, `List<object> productsasObjects = new List<Product>();` will not compile, it doesn't make sense, as i explained earlier already... If that would complie, it would allow me to add a string (strings are objects) to your product list like `productsasObjects.Add("Hello World");`, which of course would make the universe explode. Please take some time to research and experiment with that stuff (either in VS or dotnetfiddle) if you are aren't sure about this...

Comment: (By the way, one of the downvotes is mine, due to the false statement/example with regard to co/contravariance in your answer. If you fix that and i don't seem to remove the downvote within 24h after the correction, don't hesitate to send me a comment reminding to do so...)

Comment: @elgonzo: removed that part.

Comment: There goes my downvote. Farewell! You have been a good companion, if only for a short time ;-b